# gcp dataflow templates, ERROR: (gcloud.beta.dataflow.jobs.run) INVALID_ARGUMENT: There is no support for job type with environment version

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

full error

ERROR: (gcloud.beta.dataflow.jobs.run) INVALID_ARGUMENT: (4361fe83f99d0cfe): There is no support for job type  with environment version . Please try upgrading the SDK to the latest version. You can find the instructions on installing the latest SDK at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/installing-beam-sdk. If that doesn't work, please contact the Cloud Dataflow team for assistance at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/support.

staging command

```
mvn compile exec:java  -Dexec.mainClass=com.jobs.wordcount.TextToPubsub  -Dexec.args="--runner=DataflowRunner \
          --project=my_project \
          --stagingLocation=gs://bucket_name/tmp/staging \
          --templateLocation=gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Stream_GCS_Text_to_Cloud_PubSub_metadata"
```

run command

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run template_test \
--gcs-location gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Stream_GCS_Text_to_Cloud_PubSub_metadata \
--staging-location=gs:/my_bucket/tmp/staging \
--parameters \
inputFilePattern=gs://bucket_nam/input/*.json,\
outputTopic=projects/my_project/topics/testTopic
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>word_count_cicd_test</groupId>
    <artifactId>word_count_cicd_test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>[2.20.0, 2.99)</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
        <version>[2.20.0, 2.99)</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

The java code and the metadata template is provided by google

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#gcstexttocloudpubsubstream

gcloud version

```
bash-3.2$ gcloud version
    Google Cloud SDK 278.0.0
    beta 2019.05.17
    bq 2.0.52
    core 2020.01.24
    gsutil 4.47
```

I am getting the same error when launching in the console. I think it might have to do with this feature being in beta.

Comment: What version of the Cloud SDK are you using? (`gcloud version`)

Comment: gcloud version added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Stream_GCS_Text_to_Cloud_PubSub_metadata is not a valid template. It is the metadata file for the template, gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Stream_GCS_Text_to_Cloud_PubSub.

If you want to run Google's provided version of the template, you can set `--gcs_location=gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Stream_GCS_Text_to_Cloud_PubSub` in your gcloud command.

If you want to create your own template, you will have to use your own GCS bucket in templateLocation in your staging command.